# Entire function with finite number of zeros in the closed upper half complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, roots, entire-functions

Let $g_+:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C $ be a function such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(t)|dt$ is finite, $g_+$ is not the zero function nor the the function zero except in a zero measure set, and $\forall t <0$ $g_+(t)=0$. Let $\lambda\in \mathbb R$ and $f= \lambda + \int_0^{\infty}g_+(t)e^{iyt}dt$. Suppose $f$ is an entire function and that there are positive real numbers, $a$ and $A$, such that for all $z\in \{x+iy \in \mathbb C \mid y \leq 0 \}$ $|f(z)| \leq A e^{a|Im(z)|}$.

I found the following claim for $\lambda = 1$. Since the function $f$ converges uniformly to 1 as $z \to \infty$ in $\{x+iy \in \mathbb C \mid y \geq 0 \}$ and is entire, then it can only have a finite number of zeros in $\{x+iy \in \mathbb C \mid y \geq 0 \}$.

My question is how to prove that claim. I think I can prove it for $\{x+iy \in \mathbb C \mid y > 0 \}$ (I want it for the closure) using the following steps ( I don't mind another road, this is the closest one I have found, or any help or bibliography would be very much appreciated).

1.-Prove for all $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ $h_f(\theta) = \limsup_{r \to \infty} \frac{ln|f(re^{i\theta})|}{r} = 0$, where $h_f$ is the indicator function.

2.- Use the following theorem,
to obtain that: $\lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{n(r,0,\pi)}{r} = 0$, where $n(r,0,\pi)$ is the number of zeros from $\{x+iy \in \mathbb C \mid y \geq 0 \}$, the function $f$ is of exponential type and so its order is one.

The theorem I previously talked about is. If a holomorphic function $F(z)$ of order $\rho(r)$ has completely regular growth within an angle $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$, then for all values of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ $( \theta_1 < \alpha_1 < \alpha 2 < \theta_2)$ except possibly for a denumerable set the following limit exists:
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi \rho}s_F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) = \lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{n(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)}{r^{\rho(r)}}, $$
where
$$s_F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) = \left[ h_F'(\alpha_2)-h_F'(\alpha_1)+\rho^2 \int_{\alpha_1}^{\alpha_2}h_F(\phi)d\phi \right]. $$
The exceptional denumerable set can only consist of points for which $h_F'(\alpha+0) \neq h_F'(\alpha-0)$.

Thank you very much for taking your time to read my question.

Comment: Your definition of $f$ is unclear. Is it $f(z) = \lambda + \int_0^{\infty} g_+(t) e^{i t z} dt$? Besides, what do you mean by "f converges uniformly to 1 as $z \to \infty$"? The uniform convergence makes sense on a fixed domain.

Comment: If by uniform convergence, you mean that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a compact $K_{\varepsilon}$ such that $|f(z)-1| < \varepsilon$ for all $z \not \in K_{\varepsilon}$ with $\mathrm{Im}(z) \geqslant 0$, then it is clear that $f$ has only finitely many zeroes in this closed half-plane.

Comment: @halbaroth what I used as $f$ converges uniformly to 1 as $z \to \infty$ is: for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $R>0$, that not depends on $\theta$, such that if $r>R$ and $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $|f(z)-1|<\epsilon$. Which is equivalent to what you say. But I still don't see why $f$ has only finitely many zeroes in this closed half-plane. With your formulation I have a neighbourhood of infinity intersected with $\{ z \in \mathbb C \mid Im(z) \geq 0 \}$. I think I'm missing some knowledge to see what you see.

Comment: How did you prove this uniform convergence? It is clear that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\beta \in (0, \pi)$, there exists $R > 0$ such that for all $\theta \in (\beta, \pi-\beta)$ and $r \in (0, R)$, $|f(re^{i\theta})-1| < \varepsilon$. In other words, $f$ converges uniformly to $1$ in any proper sectors in the half-plane. But it is not clear that $f$ converges uniformly to $1$ in the closed half-plane $\mathcal{H}$. If it was the case, it will exist a neighbourhood of $\infty$ in which $|f| > \frac{1}{2}$. Thus, all the zeroes of $f$ in $\mathcal{H}$ would be in a compact and so finite.

Comment: @halbaroth, Thanks I now see that if it was the case...Thus, all zeros of $f$ in $\mathcal H$... and while rewriting the proof I realized I had a mistake, and you are right about the sectors. I need to look more into it in order to prove it for $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: @halbaroth, seems like its true, the proof for the proposition on the real line is called Riemann-Lesbesgue lemma. It's probably true for $[0\pi]$ because of what the claim says and in this webpage https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma  in the other versions section, it says it can be done for the Laplace transform and it hold for $|z|$ with $Re(z) \geq 0$. I'll think more about it and look in some bibliography for it, thanks again.